# How to make a stacked barchart in ggplot from a long dataframe format?

Tags: r, ggplot2, bar-chart, geom-bar, stacked-chart

I have a long dataframe format which is created like this:

```
testAppVectorJG <- c(17, 155, 200, 200, 382, 499, 548, 548, 642, 642, 699, 699)
testVectorJG <- c(testAppVectorJG[1], diff(testAppVectorJG))

testAppVectorJW <- c(145, 209, 366, 548, 548, 613, 746, 928, 1064, 1266, 1371, 1573)
testVectorJW <- c(testAppVectorJW[1], diff(testAppVectorJW))

test_df <- data.frame(puntenvector = c(testVectorJG, testVectorJW),
                      team = c(rep("Jasper & Gijs", length(testAppVectorJG)),
                               rep("Jaap & Wil", length(testAppVectorJW))),
                      Rondenummer = as.factor(1:length(testVectorJG)))
```

I want to make a stacked bar chart with a bar per 'Rondenummer' (i.e. number of the round played). I want to see the percentage/distribution of points per round per team.

So far I have tried:

```
ggplot(data = test_df, aes(Rondenummer)) +
    geom_bar(aes(x = puntenvector, fill = team))
```

But then I get:

```
Warning message:
position_stack requires non-overlapping x intervals
```

And not at all the plot I want. How do I achieve this fairly simple plot?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Maybe something like this ?

```
library(ggplot2)

ggplot(data = test_df, aes(Rondenummer, puntenvector, fill = team)) +
   geom_bar(stat='identity')
```

[image]

If we want to include the values in the plot we can use `label` with `geom_text`

```
ggplot(data = test_df, 
      aes(Rondenummer, puntenvector, fill = team, label = puntenvector)) +
      geom_bar(stat='identity') +
      geom_text(position = position_stack(vjust = 0.5))
```

[image]

And finally if we want to reverse the order of `Rondenummer` after `coord_flip()` we can add `scale_x_discrete` and reverse the levels.

```
 ggplot(data = test_df, 
   aes(Rondenummer, puntenvector, fill = team, label = puntenvector)) +
   geom_bar(stat='identity') +
   geom_text(position = position_stack(vjust = 0.5)) +
   coord_flip() + 
   scale_x_discrete(limits = rev(levels(test_df$Rondenummer)))
```

[image]

Comment: Yes! That's exactly what I was looking for, thanks!

Comment: Could there be any way to include the value of each score in the bars? So that for round 1 it displays '17' in the blue and '145' in the red?

Comment: @JNab We can use `geom_text`. Updated the answer with that.

Comment: One last question though; when I now want to make it horizontal I can add `+ coord_flip()` to it, but then it goes from 12 on the top to 1 on the bottom. How can I then reverse that?

Comment: @JNab starting from 1 at the bottom to 12 at the top is the natural way of displaying it but if you need to reverse it we can use `scale_x_discrete`. I have updated the answer.